# Swift JSONDecoder type mismatch on parsing ISO8601 DateInterval

Tags: swift, iso8601, jsondecoder, dateinterval

I'm trying to parse next sample DateInterval values an Api suplies following ISO 8601 format:

```
[
    {"ISO8601":"PT10M","text":"time: 00:10"},
    {"ISO8601":"PT1H10M","text":"time: 01:10"},
    {"ISO8601":"PT3H20M","text":"time: 03:20"}
]
```

to next model:

```
struct DTOTest:Codable {
    var ISO8601:DateInterval
    var text:String
}
```

But I get next mismatch exception:

> Type 'Dictionary' mismatch Context: Expected to decode
>   Dictionary but found a string/data instead. CodingPath:
>   [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0),
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: "ISO8601", intValue: nil)]

Mi decoding function uses 8601 strategy, so it should read it properly, and indeed it works Ok with ISO 8601 Date:

```
static func decode<T:Decodable>(data:Data, completion: @escaping (Result<T,NetworkError>) -> Void) {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

    do {
        let retval = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        completion(.success(retval))

    } catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
        var reason = "Type '\(type)' mismatch"
        reason += "\nContext: \(context.debugDescription)"
        reason += "\nCodingPath: \(context.codingPath)"
        completion(.failure(.requestError(reason: reason)))
    } catch {
        let reason = "Error '\(error.localizedDescription)'"
        completion(.failure(.requestError(reason: reason)))
    }

}
```

What may be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `iso8601` date decoding strategy supports only the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` to decode `String` to `Date`.

It's impossible to decode an ISO8601 string directly to `DateInterval` with `JSONDecoder` anyway.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, I'll have to build a parser from String then

Comment: Consider also that `DateInterval` is a struct with start date and end date or duration, you probably mean `TimeInterval` which represents only a duration according to the ISO8601 string.

Comment: Yes, TimeInterval was my first option, but it is expressed in seconds and as far as I know JSONDecoder does not parse it from ISO8601 either. The goal is to read ISO8601 interval dates and offer the user a time picker to edit them

Comment: `PT1H10M` is a duration of 70 seconds. The  ISO8601 *interval* syntax requires at least a start date.

Comment: PT1H10M is indeed a duration of 70 minutes according to ISO8601 syntax. I finally built a parser from scratch for TimeInterval. Thanks for your clues.